# Неправильный редирект

Tags: python, url, flask

Есть функция для редиректа укороченных URL на их оригинал -

[image: Код функции]

Например, в БД есть следующая запись :

- original_url : stackoverflow.com
- short_url : xYz

Проблема в том, что при запросе

> 127.0.0.1:5000/xYz

URL в адресной строке меняется на

> 127.0.0.1:5000/stackoverflow.com

, с ошибкой "The requested URL not found on server".

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если у вас ссылка original_url относительная, то она и будет открываться относительно вашего текущего сайта. Если вы хотите открыть другой сайт, значит пишите абсолютную ссылку целиком `https://stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1):

```py
url = link.original_url
if not url.startswith('http') or not url.startswith('/')
    url = 'http://' + url
return redirect(url, code=302)
```